# remote secure wss is not working on local site in WebView (Windows Phone, SCRIPT 12057)

Tags: ssl, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I'v developing on Windows Phone WebView app.
The site of WebView use remove service by wss.
So there is local site(in private network 192.168.x.x)

MainWebView.Navigate(new Uri("192.168.x.x));
and the site call wss://xxxx.xxxx.xx/websockets

I get this error in VS Javascript Console:
SCRIPT12057: null
onSocketError! wss://xxxx.xxxx.xx/websockets
on emulator of Windows Phone 8.1(so there is IE11 engine)

this is HTTP Error 12057 - SSL Revocation (http://www.genopro.com/ssl/)

Do you have an idea how to fix it for my case?

Comment: I installed the certifcate for remote site

Comment: and if webView use remote site with same url for websocket it working well.